# how to get top column values based on the sum of other column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So basically I have this dataframe called df_genre

```
userid|genre|total_streams
123   |Pop  |4252
124   |Pop  |220
125   |k-Pop|111
126   |jaz  |1092
127   |Hip Hop |1102
....
```

I basically have 5234 genre type and each line contains the userid with the total number of streams for each genre he played. what I want is to get the top 20 genre with the most streams.

what I did is:

```
df_genre = df_genre.groupby(['userid','genre'])['total_streams'].sum().reset_index()
df_genre_sorted = df_genre.sort_values(by=['total_streams'], ascending=False)
df_genre_sorted.drop_duplicates(subset='genre', keep='first', inplace=True)
df_genre_sorted.head(20)
```

the result was:

```
userid|genre|total_streams
123   |Pop    |425225
124   |k-Pop  |120482
125   |Pop    |27393
126   |jaz    |2849
127   |Hip Hop|241102
920   |K-Pop  |82910
...
```

so basically it gave me the top 20 but there are some values that are repetitive for example I got 2 Pop and 2 k-Pop even tho they are the same. how can I combine them and keep the actual top 20 with no duplicate inside of them?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know any "easy" way to do this, you'll need to clean your data, one way or another. One thing you can do, for instance, is only grouping on the lowercased genre instead of the genre. Also pay attention to any trailing space.
`df["genre"].map(lambda x: x.lower().strip())`

This will not resolve the problem of typing errors (`jaz` vs `jazz` if it is the same thing)